# find multiple occurence in given string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How i can find multiple occurence in given string in vb.net

For e.g my string is two times : 1234567

1234567,Desction,1.32

1234555,Desction,2.30

1234556,Desction,2.30

1234557,Desction,2.30

1234567,Desction,1.32

I want to put this two rows into a Dropdown Menu which is on my Form

Its Urgent

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to clarrify a little. Do you have a List<string> and you wish to find the duplicates in this list?

Comment: Yes please elaborate. What do you mean by 2 times? How would you like to populate the dropdown? What dropdown control are your refering to? Winform or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

**Lets say that what you need is to find all duplicates in a list of strings**, Using a bit of linq you can try

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)() 
list.Add("1234567,Desction,1.32") 
list.Add("1234555,Desction,2.30") 
list.Add("1234556,Desction,2.30") 
list.Add("1234557,Desction,2.30") 
list.Add("1234567,Desction,1.32") 
Dim duplicates = From s In list _ 
    Group s By sIntog _ 
    Where g.Count() > 1 _ 
    Select g 

For Each s In duplicates 
    Dim duplicate As String = s.Key 
Next
```

Then in the For Each, you can populate the DropDown Items from the strings.

Well, in that case you can try something like

```
Dim duplicates As New List(Of String)() 

For iString As Integer = 1 To list.Count - 1 
    If Not duplicates.Contains(list(iString - 1)) Then 
        For iCompare As Integer = iString To list.Count - 1 
            If list(iString - 1) = list(iCompare) Then 
                duplicates.Add(list(iString - 1)) 
                Exit For 
            End If 
        Next 
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: Actually i am using VB.Net 2003 ans this code is not working on that.

How to convert into .Net 2003 of your code and try.

Kindly help on this.